# Set array values as hidden values in form jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

the selected value is: *["4", "5", "6"]*

The code which I have now:

```
$.each(selected, function(){
    $('input[type=hidden][name="ids[]"]').val(selected);
});
```

is resulting in:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "4,5,6"
]
```

I need these selected elements to be their own index of the array so that I can loop through it in my controller. Could someone please help me assign the seperate array values to a hidden value

Comment: `array[0].split(',')`

Comment: can you please tell me where??  @Laazo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create new array using `.each()` function to loop on all values.
2. It accepts 2 parameter index and value

```js
 var selected = ["4", "5", "6"]
var arr = []
var obj = {}
$.each(selected, function(i,v){
   
   obj[v]=v
   
});
arr.push(obj)
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Array and push the Results into it.

```
var values = [];
$('input[type=hidden][name="ids[]"]').each(function ( index, element ) {
    values.push( ... );
});
```